# C# Download PDF From Webpage, NO URL or UID available

Tags: c#, javascript, html, pdf

Like the title says I have to download a PDF from a webpage I'm on (after I have logged in).

The only problem is that the page looks like this (part of the page ofc):

```
<fieldset class="print_mode">
    <legend> Pozostałe opcje </legend>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:nullObject();" onclick="javascript:alert('Wybierz numer strony, którą chcesz pobrać');" >Zapisz na dysk (JPEG):  
                <a class="szczegoly_strona" href="/tools/GetJpgFile.aspx?id=64604627&amp;page=1">1</a>  
                <a class="szczegoly_strona" href="/tools/GetJpgFile.aspx?id=64604627&amp;page=2">2</a>  
                <a class="szczegoly_strona" href="/tools/GetJpgFile.aspx?id=64604627&amp;page=3">3</a>  
                <a class="szczegoly_strona" href="/tools/GetJpgFile.aspx?id=64604627&amp;page=4">4</a>  
                <a class="szczegoly_strona" href="/tools/GetJpgFile.aspx?id=64604627&amp;page=5">5</a> 
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:nullObject();" onclick="javascript:PrintVersion('/pdf/newPdf/print.php','PrintVersionForm',1);" >Zapisz na dysk (PDF)</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

What I would click in the browser is the "Zapisz na dysk (PDF)" link, which corresponds to some text in the bottom of the page that you can click and this will automatically download the pdf for you.So what I need is to know:

- How can I click that/download it?
- Even better if I can directly decide the path where to save it.

Comment: There is not enough context in this question. Is this in a C# app, or is a web browser involved? Do you have the HTML and need to extract the link? Is the link dynamic, and if so, what parts are dynamic? If it's not dynamic, what's the issue? Downloading a file (once you know the URL) in C# is easy (`(new WebClient()).DownloadFile("http://mysite.com/myfile.txt", @"c:\myfile.txt")`), so I am assuming you are asking something more..

Comment: Hello. Yes it is an app in c#. I have the link which directs me to a page which has 2 "links" in the bottom which you can click and it will download the pdf as shown here:  <a href="javascript:nullObject();" onclick="javascript:PrintVersion('/pdf/newPdf/print.php','PrintVersionForm',1);" >Zapisz na dysk (PDF)</a>

I am just wondering how can i do this!? if this was a normal button you would click for downloading there would be no problem as I would do: "browser.Button("Button"); (use Watin) but this is not a button and it might be easy but I am not getting how could i do this.

Answer (score 1):

Check in FireBug, Chrome Developer tools or IE Developer tools what is the url from which the PDF file is downloaded.

I'm suspecting it will be something like /pdf/newPdf/print.php <-- looking at the code you posted.

Anyways you can embed a browser control on a form and browse to the url and click the button programmatically.

Or you can use something like '[Watin](http://watin.org/)" for it.

Comment: Hey I use Watin (today for the first time) but I don't get what you mean by "check what is the url from which the pdf is downloaded).
The only clue I get when I right click on the link and choose "inspect element" with chrome, is that line I posted in the code: <a href="javascript:nullObject();" onclick="javascript:PrintVersion('/pdf/newPdf/print.php','PrintVersionForm',1);" >Zapisz na dysk (PDF)</a>
Any thoughts??

Comment: ok first small step. I am telling you this cause I didnt mention it:
The pdf i wanna download is made of several jpegs pictures of articles.
In the pageby default is shown the first image of the 5(in this case). you can download the whole thing as a whole in pdf or jpeg(havent tried if it's 1 file). I need it in pdf. 
When I click on network I can see the link to where that jpeg is located! so that might help. however what I want is to download the whole thing as a pdf. Ideas? How could I just programmatically click that link?

Comment: What do you suggest?? do you need more info??

Comment: When you click, it's going to tell your browser to request a URL where it will actually download something. You need to look for that redirect or request, and you'll get the URL.